# Why can we use undefined object in Javascript function declaration?

Tags: javascript, function

Chromium WebUI has a [cr.js](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/ui/webui/resources/js/cr.js) file, which offers `cr.define( name, fun )` method, for modulization.  All the porperties of the object that `fun` returns, will be added to the `name` namescope object.

In chromium browser bookmarks manager page(chrome://bookmarks), a Javascript source file named `bmm.js` is loaded.
This is a Javascript module in bookmark manager.

Below is part of the [bmm.js](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/chrome/browser/resources/bookmark_manager/js/bmm.js) file, using `cr.define()`, which defines a lot of methods, then add them to the `bmm` object.

```
cr.define('bmm', function() {
  'use strict';

  function contains(parent, descendant) {
    if (descendant.parentId == parent.id)
      return true;
    // the bmm.treeLookup contains all folders
    var parentTreeItem = bmm.treeLookup[descendant.parentId];
    if (!parentTreeItem || !parentTreeItem.bookmarkNode)
      return false;
    return this.contains(parent, parentTreeItem.bookmarkNode);
  }

  // ... more function definitions ...

  return {
    contains: contains,
    isFolder: isFolder,
    loadSubtree: loadSubtree,
    loadTree: loadTree,
    addBookmarkModelListeners: addBookmarkModelListeners
  };
});
```

The 2nd argument of `cr.define();` is an anonymous function expression, it is parsed and executed, the returned value is an object, which is then passed to `cr.define()` as argument.

Notice in function declaration of `function contains()`, there uses `bmm` object, which should be undefined at the time this function body is being parsed.

Why can we use `bmm` and its method `treeLookup` before they are defined ?

Does function body of contains() is parsed and saved as a syntax tree, within which many nodes are tokens=undefined?

It can not be parsed and saved in raw source code, because that means it is not parsed at all.

Comment: _“the returned value is an object, which is then passed to cr.define() as argument”_… actually it looks like the function itself is passed to `cr.define` as an argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The 2nd argument of `cr.define()` is an anonymous function expression, it is parsed and executed, the returned value is an object, which is then passed to `cr.define()` as argument.

In fact it's not. It's just passed as a function to `cr.define`, without being called. It's executed from [within there](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/ui/webui/resources/js/cr.js#273):

```
var exports = fun();
```

> Notice in function declaration of `function contains()`, there uses `bmm` object, which should be undefined at the time this function body is being parsed.

Yes. And that doesn't matter at all. It's just a free variable with the name `bmm`.

It will be resolved only when the function is called.

> Why can we use `bmm` and its method `treeLookup` before they are defined?

They are not used - `contains` is not called. They're just identifiers at parse time. The method call will be dispatched dynamically only when the code is actually executed.

> Is the function body of `contains()` parsed and saved as a syntax tree?

Yes. That's what parsing does.

> within which many nodes are tokens=undefined?

No. A syntax tree does not store values. The records for storing those are created at runtime, as are the values themselves. Only then assignments and lookups will take place.